# Sed script to delete everything in <head> tag except the <title> and insert script

Tags: html, sed, awk

I want to remove everything inside the `<head>` tag except the `<title>` in an html file, and also insert a script into the `<head>` tag after this is done. I don't want to delete the `<head>` tag itself.

Is this possible using Sed?

Comment: Are the opening tags always on a single line for head and title and the closing tags too? Or is the whole head on a single line? For a generated file, which always looks the same, it might be possible, but if you don't know, and have to handle `<head x='...'>`-situations, it's not to recommend.

Comment: is there any other way to do this? with or without sed?

Comment: as in modifying html files before they are rendered

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to parse HTML is not a good choice. See [this famous article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for a full discussion

Comment: The article isn't famous, but a foolish rant. Why aren't arguments presented? Don't they know them? Do you know them? Then name them.

Comment: @user-unknown a simple SO search reveals what you are asking about, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege

Comment: Well, @Frederik, *that* is a useful comment, but Bohemian's isn't. It is an unprofessional waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use a DOM Parser for this type of work since any regex you try will break at some point using sed or any of its variant. Since you've asked for an alternative in your comments consider following code in PHP:

```
$content = '
<HTML>
<HEAD>
   <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <title>
   Page Title Goes here
   </title>
   <script>
       var str = "ZZZZZ1233@qq.edu";
   </script>    
</HEAD>
';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$head='
<head>
<script>
   // your javascript goes here
   var x="foo";
</script>
';
$headTag = $dom->getElementsByTagName("head")->item(0);
if ($headTag != null) {
   $title = $headTag->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0);
   if ($title != null)
      $head .= '<title>' . $title->textContent . '</title>
';
}
$head .= '</head>';
var_dump($head);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(118) "
<head>
<script>
   // your javascript goes here
   var x="foo";
</script>
<title>Page Title Goes here</title>
</head>"
```